# Handling count of characters with diacritics in R

Tags: r, unicode, character-encoding, nlp, linguistics

I'm trying to get the number of characters in strings with characters with diacritics, but I can't manage to get the right result.

```
> x <- "n̥ala"
> nchar(x)
[1] 5
```

What I want to get is is `4`, since `n̥` should be considered one character (i.e. diacritics shouldn't be considered characters on their own, even with more than one diacritic stacked on a base character).

How can I get this kind of result?

Comment: In which language is used this diacritics? Maybe you can find the right encoding and set it.

Comment: It is in International Phonetic Alphabet, so no particular language and almost any combination is virtually possible.

Comment: This might work, but I'm not experienced with encodings and I have no idea if it's suitable for other special characters... `nchar(gsub("<U\\+\\d{4}>", "", enc2native("n̥ala")))`

Comment: Same comment as above, this looks better and doesn't read the <U+0000> stuff: `nchar(iconv("n̥ala", to="ASCII", sub=""))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. The idea is that phonetic alphabets can have an unicode representation and then:

Use `Unicode` package; it provide the function `Unicode_alphabetic_tokenizer` that:

> Tokenization first replaces the elements of x by their Unicode
>   character sequences. Then, the non- alphabetic characters (i.e., the
>   ones which do not have the Alphabetic property) are replaced by
>   blanks, and the corresponding strings are split according to the
>   blanks.

After this I used the `nchar` but because the splitting it two substrings of the previous function I used a `sum`.

```
sum(nchar(Unicode_alphabetic_tokenizer(x)))
[1] 4
```

I believe this package can be very useful in such cases, but I am not an expert and I do not know if my solution works for all problems that involve phonetic alphabets. Maybe other examples might be useful to state the validity of my solution.

### It works well

Here is another example:

```
> x <- "e̯ ʊ̯"
> x
[1] "e̯ ʊ̯"
> nchar(x)
[1] 5
> sum(nchar(Unicode_alphabetic_tokenizer(x)))
[1] 2
```

p.s.
there is only one `"` in the code but copying and pasting it, the second one appears. I do not know why this happens.

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually, this solution wouldn't fit my bigger problem, which is tabulating the occurrences of phones (a phone is here a character plus diacritics if present) in a string. With this method, [n] and [n̥] would be counted as two instances of the same phone, which is not desirable. I'll open a new question stating exactly the tabulating problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the **qdap** package that I maintain:

```
x <- "n?ala"

library(qdap)
character_count(word)
## [1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do workarounds. Here's one:

```
dia.count <- function(string) {
  y <- unlist(strsplit(string, ''))
  length(grep('[A-Za-z0-9]', y, value=T))
}
dia.count(x)
[1] 4
```

Methods for dealing directly with character encoding is preferable. This is again, a workaround. In the general case, there may be packages or combinations of functions to address your issue comprehensively.

## Update

Here is another workaround provided by comment:

```
nchar(sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', x))
[1] 4
```

The `dia.count` function looks for capital and lowercase letters along with numbers in the string. The added script does the opposite; it eliminates all string tokens that are not letters, capital or otherwise. credit @akrun

The best I could find in the package `stringi` is `str_enc_toascii` which gives:

```
stri_enc_toascii(x)
[1] "n\032ala"
```

Given that output, subbing out everything but letters will provide the desired output.

```
nchar(sub('[^A-Za-z]', '', stri_enc_toascii(x)))
[1] 4
```

A nice balance between a general answer and a quick script is found in the comments:

```
nchar(iconv("n̥ala", to="ASCII", sub=""))
[1] 4
```

This uses the `base R` function `iconv`, that converts the string for you. credit @Molx

Comment: Though, I am not sure if this is a general workaround.  I think `stringi` have some options, also I felt the `iconv` in the comments may be more general.

Comment: I will add, but if the commenter can still add it as an answer if they choose.

Comment: This won't work if the base characters aren't ASCII – like eg. `ŋ̥ala` –, which is quite common in IPA.

Comment: the examples are all based on non-ASCII cases @lenz

Comment: yes sure, @plafort, but `nchar(iconv("ŋ̥ala", to="ASCII", sub=""))` will give you 3 instead of 4 (note the small hook on the first character `ŋ`)

Comment: The output and code is right there. Maybe we're talking past each other. The script you mentioned above provides the desired output as posted. Why would I show `4` as the output if it is `3` in truth as you say? Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: Your code works fine for the example in the question, where all base characters are plain ASCII. However, a typical IPA string may very well contain non-ASCII base characters, as shown in my modified example in the comment. I'm trying to say that your solution is not generally applicable.

Comment: Just try this example: `nchar(iconv("bæd", to="ASCII", sub=""))`. It returns 2, not 3.

Comment: When I said 'addresses' I was not implying that it solves general cases. Please reread my answer in its entirety. @lenz

Comment: When you say a regex like `[^A-Za-z]` will sub out "everything but letters", then you are implying that characters like `ŋ`, `æ`, or `ɛ` are not letters, which is clearly wrong. I see that you mention the need of other packages for a more comprehensive solution; if that's what you mean by "addressing" general cases, then I understand your point.

Comment: Yes exactly @lenz, "Methods for dealing directly with character encoding is preferable. This is again, a workaround." I understand completely that there are many situations that a hack will not solve, especially when it is written to solve a specific problem. I find character encoding interesting. How would you get a character count with the special characters?

Comment: The answer by SabDeM seems to solve this. Or you can use [character categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category), as in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551549/tabulating-characters-with-diacritics-in-r), which uses them in a regex.